# os.rename() fails, in use by another process

Tags: python, file

So I'm trying to rename a file, and it keeps saying "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." But I know it's not being used by another process so I'm not sure what's going on. Here's my code

```
while self.fileSet.hasMoreFiles():
    file = self.fileSet.nextFile()
    periodIndex=file.find(".")
    extension = file[periodIndex:]
    baseName=file[:periodIndex]
    self.newFile=open(file, 'w+')
    self.backupName = baseName + "_bak" + extension
    os.rename(file, baseName + "_bak" + extension)
    self.newFile=open(file, 'w+')
    self.writeNew()
```

Comment: "But I know it's not being used by another process" - how do you know this? Did you check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You open the file 2 lines before you try to call `os.rename` on it, but you don't close it before trying to rename it, so your own program still has it open.

Call `self.newFile.close()` before the `os.rename()` and you should avoid that error - or better yet, don't call `open()` at all before the rename, given that you're not actually using the opened file (and you open it right after the rename anyway).

---

Some tangential notes:

- You shouldn't name a variable `file` - there's already a type named `file` that you're shadowing if you do that.
- You duplicate a lot of code - for instance, you just created `self.backupName` on the line above the rename, but then you re-calculate it. Why not just pass `self.backupName` as the second argument to `os.rename()`?
- You can skip the `find` call and subsequent slicing by using [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

All in all, you could condense your code down to this:

```
while self.fileSet.hasMoreFiles():
    curFile = self.fileSet.nextFile()
    baseName, extension = os.path.splitext(curFile)
    self.backupName = baseName + "_bak" + extension
    os.rename(curFile, self.backupName)
    self.newFile = open(curFile, 'w+')
    self.writeNew()
```

Comment: This answered my question and then some. Ha the duplicate/not-so-great code was a result of me trying to get it done last night. But thanks for your help, that was a silly thing for me to over look.

Comment: I tried to `os.Rename` in golang with `defer myFile.Close()` at the begining of my function. However I was trying to rename in that function, before `defer` was run. This answer helped me. I did `myFile.Close()` before calling `os.Rename()`. Although, everything run fine on Linux while testing, in Windows it could not rename. Thanks for the idea.